# How can you interpret one of the parameters of optimal consumption at the Merton portfolio problem?

Tags: optimization, consumption, risk-aversion, elasticity-of-substitution, portfolio-theory

**Statement:** Let the dynamics of wealth of the agent satisfy
$$dX_{t} =
 \pi_tX_t\Big(\mu dt+\sigma dB_{t}\Big)- c_t X_t dt, \qquad \textrm{with}\quad X_0=x_0 \in \mathbb{R},$$
where $(\pi,c)$ is an investment-consumption ($\pi$ - fraction of wealth to invest, $c$ - fraction of wealth to consume).

Under standard Merton optimization problem the agent is to maximize the expected utility $$J(\pi,c) =\mathbb{E}\Big[\int_0^TU(c_tX_t) dt +  U(X_T)\Big],$$
under CRRA power utility $$U(x) = \frac{1}{1-\frac1\delta}x^{\frac1{1-\frac1\delta}}, \quad \delta > 0, \delta\neq 1,$$ so $\delta$ plays a role of *risk-tolerance* parameter.

The optimal plan is then given by $$\pi^* = \frac{\mu}{\sigma^2}\delta,\quad c^*_t=\Big( \frac1{\beta}-\big(1-\frac1\beta\big)e^{-\beta(T-t)}\Big)^{-1},$$
where $\beta = \frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}\delta(1-\delta).$

**Question:** How can I interpret $\beta$ at this point? I have seen that $\frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}\delta$ is sometimes referred to as *expected portfolio return*. But what is the meaning when I multiply it by $1-\delta$? If $\delta > 1$, it can be negative. I would call it *effective expected portfolio return*, but am not sure. If you can provide any reference, that would be perfect.
Thanks in advance!

**P.S.** I was adapting my model to the standard Merton one, sorry for any discrepancies.

Comment: Your parametrization of CRRA via $\delta$ seems a bit strange. In any case, the $\delta(1-\delta)$ expression in consumption share $\beta$ should reflect the elasticity of intertemporal substitution.

Comment: @Michael, thanks for your answer. That is an interesting perspective and thanks for pointing this out. However, as I look at the definition of the elasticity of intertemporal substitution, it follows that it should be equal to $\frac1\delta$, or risk-aversion coefficient in other words. At this point I cannot see, how it can relate to $\beta$.
If I am wrong, please, let me know. It would be nice as well, if you can refer me to some literature.

Comment: First, I meant $\delta$, sorry.
Do I understand correctly, that for running utility it essentially means the same. But that is interesting, as $\delta$ coming from terminal wealth optimization means *risk-tolerance*, but the one from the running integral optimization of consumption is an *elasticity of intertemporal substitution* and we require them to coincide for solvability.

Am super strange seeing it for the first time. Again, would be glad if you refer me somewhere.